A story where a character can make things (and, occasionally, people) disappear
I think this is a novel, maybe a novella, but not shorter than that. I also believe it is a rather well known story, but I read it very long ago (40 years or so) and I remember just one detail, though I think it is a very important one.
The main character (not POV character) has special powers, including making things disappear. Usually, only useless things that bothered him (yes, he is male).
Someone got the idea to use an ultra-fast movie camera when something was put in a situation to disappear. It did not happen instantaneously, as it seemed to an human observer. In the movie, when considerably slowed down, the object looked smaller and smaller, not like shrinking, rather like receding farther and farther away very fast, but not in any of the ordinary dimensions, no wall nor ceiling nor floor were crossed, it is as if it was receding in some "other direction".
IIRC, in one occasion, someone had the stupid idea to threaten him violently, and also ended up nobody knows where.
That is all I can remember, maybe it is enough...

This is Robert Heinlein's Stranger in a Strange Land - the character who can make things (and people) disappear is Valentine Michael Smith, a human raised by Martians. One of his Earth human friends (Jubal Harshaw) sets up cameras to record (from three directions) what happens when Mike "disappears" something and each camera shows the object shrinking as if moving further away before disappearing completely.  At another point in the book a team of armed police attack - and at least one disappears when Mike wishes him to be gone.
This article summarizes the chapters that discuss this matter:

Jubal asks Mike about making Berquist and the officer disappear. Mike is unable to explain what he did, as there are not words in English for it. Jubal asks Mike to make a box disappear. Mike asks if the box is a "wrong thing," for he will only make wrong things disappear. Jubal asks Jill to throw the box at his head and Mike indeed makes it disappear in mid-air. Jubal asks Mike how close to something he needs to be to exercise this power. Mike explains that it is not a matter of distance but of knowledge of wrongness.


Duke and Jubal watch the film of Mike's disappearing demonstration. In slow motion, they can see the box that Jill threw at Jubal seem to shrink and recede into the distance. They then watch footage from another angle and see the same thing: the box seems to recede into the distance. Theoretically it should be impossible, in three dimensions, for the box to recede in two directions at once. They realize that Mike has an ability to turn objects in a direction that is perpendicular to all three dimensions.


Exactly what I remember. How could I have forgotten it was Heinlein's Stranger in a Strange Land ? I just got this ultrafast camera detail in mind, unconnected with the remainder of the story. But I knew, somehow, it was a well-known one !

My biggest stress was worrying that someone else would beat me to it.

Indeed, it took you only 7 minutes ! I waited about half an hour before checking, I should have checked earlier...

Just to add; Jubal first asks Mike to stop the box from hitting him, and he actually stops the box in mid-air.

As an aside: Great book. Such an anarchist free love hippie book from such a militarist -- amazing.
